# Specifying the bounce-back address for email

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I'm having a problem getting emails to bounce to a specific email address, different to the `From` address.

A particular client requires that we send emails from a specific email address (call it `contact@clientcompany.com`).  Our Exchange admins have created an account on the Exchange box so that we can log in and send from that address.  Our Exchange server is spoofing that address / domain.  This works fine.

Unfortunately the emails sent from `contact@clientcompany.com` are not bouncing back to us.  They are presumably bouncing back to the `contact` account at `clientcompany.com` (which may or may not exist).

I've inserted a header `Return-Path=kirk.broadhurst@mycompany.com` with the assumption that [this field determines where bouncebacks are sent.](http://cr.yp.to/immhf/envelope.html)  Other documents indicate that [this field should never be populated by the originating SMTP system](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).  Other websites again talk about [a field called `Errors-To`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2076.html) which is apparently non-standard.

So - which field is the correct one, and what does it depend on?
Any ideas why my `Return-Path` is not working?

I'd really like to get Exchange to correctly bounce a message addressed to an invalid server!

**update:**

Continuing to dig, and my `Return-Path` work was only adding an extended property at the end of the header block, but Exchange appears to be still adding its own `Return-Path` value at the top.

```
Delivered-To: test@test.com 
Received: by 1.1.1.1 with SMTP ... 
Return-Path: <contact@clientcomapny.com> 
Received: from ... ... 
...
Subject: Test 
Message-ID: ... 
Return-Path: kirk.broadhurst@mycompany.com
```

According to the Microsoft.com, [I cannot set the Return-Path as it is determined by the MAIL FROM](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/exchangesvrtransport/thread/4b2a918c-0f55-4770-a4dc-d9148dff4db6/) - which seems consistent with what I've previously read.  But now I'm stuck - how do I change this MAIL FROM value programmatically within Exchange 2007?

Comment: I didn't get this working because Exchange seems to reject messages with alters mail headers.  I believe the solution lies somewhere in an Exchange configuration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check if the header is correctly set. Check the headers of your email and look for:

```
Return-Path: kirk.broadhurst@mycompany.com
```

Return-Path is the correct field according to RFC (IIRC) but not all Mail Servers implement that correctly.

Comment: Yep, that's how I'm using it.  I've confirmed that it is in the outgoing email, and I waited 12+ hours for the bounce to come back... but it hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Out of luck ;) The sender is where bounces end up. The client should create the mailbox and forward it to your internal bounce mailbox. Only clear solution.

Comment: This is the solution the system admins suggested.  I think it's probably what we'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

If a human is replying to the e-mail, and not an automated response, you may want to try using the header "Reply-To:" instead of "Return-Path:". (For example: "`Reply-To: kirk.broadhurst@mycompany.com`")